# Spotlight shortcut Cmd+Space stops working in Yosemite

Tags: spotlight

I have to go to the spotlight menu under system preferences and change and re-set the keyboard shortcut to Cmd+Space and then it starts to work again.

Has anyone else also experienced this? Anyone know what causes the shortcut to stop working?

Comment: if your settings do not stick repair the permissions in disk utility.

Comment: Haven't experienced it in weeks, theres been a number of OS X 10.10 updates. Probably something in there addressed it.

Comment: I have this issue too. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Doug El Capitan

Comment: I am on El Capitan (10.11.3) :(

Comment: ah, damn. I dunno, haven't reproduced this issue in a while now. Maybe it's some app that you've installed that may somehow interfere with spotlight or keyboard bindings or shortcuts.

Comment: I would mark the bug as "unreproducible" if that was a thing I could do. This one feels like something that Cupertino has fixed

Comment: I am experiencing this bug also.

Comment: presently experiencing this bug

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab and click Restore Defaults. Then reconfigure your shortcut.