# Spotlight stopped working

Tags: keyboard, spotlight

For some reason my spotlight shortcut stopped working yesterday my MBP running Sierra 10.12.6

I am not using BetterTouch tools, it is a very non customised install of OS X:

[Spotlight shortcut (cmd+space) no longer working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318100/spotlight-shortcut-cmdspace-no-longer-working)

Have also checked, unchecked and clicked Restore Defaults in System settings> Keyboard:
[image]

I have followed the following answer with no luck, and would like to get to the bottom of this before I do a reboot:

[Command + Space Spotlight shortcut stopped working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336409/command-space-spotlight-shortcut-stopped-working)

When I do press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> I get a ping but the usual spotlight window does not show up anywhere.

Could I have accidentally disabled the shortcut with another shortcut somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot fixed the issue.  However before the reboot, I restarted finder and the process would not start up, I could see my files in terminal but not on the desktop and could not navigate via finder windows.

Both the finder and the Spotlight issues were fixed with a reboot.